# UIAppearance Protocol for MessagesExtension App

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, uiappearance, imessage-extension

I'm working on an iOS Messages Extension app. In this app, I use google autocomplete. To style an autocomplete table, [Google recommends using the UIAppearance protocol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete#using_the_uiappearance_protocol) in the AppDelegate.m file for certain parameters, like a table view cell's selected background color. But, since message extension apps can't access the AppDelegate.swift file, how is it recommended to manage styling? Especially since Google's Autocomplete table doesn't provide built-in methods for adjusting qualities like the selected background color?